# Pepper robot keeps showing the same Image

Tags: python, robot, pepper, nao-robot, choregraphe

I am programing a pepper robot with choregraphe and when I show and image and try to show another image in the same behavior or a different behavior it shows the same image. Does anyone know how to actually show the image I want?

Comment: You should share the code of the Choregraphe box you are using to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is from a different thread, I cant find it again but make sure your show image box looks like this (look at the bottom for additional code)

```
def onLoad(self):
    pass

def onUnload(self):
    pass

def _getTabletService(self):
    tabletService = None
    try:
        tabletService = self.session().service("ALTabletService")
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.error(e)
    return tabletService

def _getAbsoluteUrl(self, partial_url):
    import os
    subPath = os.path.join(self.packageUid(), os.path.normpath(partial_url).lstrip("\\/"))
    # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
    # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
    return "http://%s/apps/%s" %(self._getTabletService().robotIp(), subPath.replace(os.path.sep, "/"))

def onInput_onStart(self):
    # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
    # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
    import time
    tabletService = self._getTabletService()
    if tabletService:
        try:
            url = self.getParameter("ImageUrl")
            if url == '':
                self.logger.error("URL of the image is empty")
            if not url.startswith('http'):
                url = self._getAbsoluteUrl(url)
            url += "?" + str(time.time())
            tabletService.showImage(url)
        except Exception as err:
            self.logger.error("Error during ShowImage : %s " % err)
            self.onStopped()
    else:
        self.logger.warning("No ALTabletService, can't display the image.")
        self.onStopped()

def onInput_onHideImage(self):
    # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
    # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
    tabletService = self._getTabletService()
    if tabletService:
        try:
            tabletService.hideImage()
        except Exception as err:
            self.logger.error("Error during HideImage : %s " % err)
            self.onStopped()
    else:
        self.logger.warning("No ALTabletService, can't hide the image.")
        self.onStopped()

def onInput_onPreLoadImage(self):
    # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
    # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
    tabletService = self._getTabletService()
    if tabletService:
        try:
            partialUrl = self.getParameter("ImageUrl")
            fullUrl = self._getAbsoluteUrl(partialUrl)
            self.logger.warning(fullUrl)
            os.remove(fullUrl)
        except Exception as err:
            self.logger.warning("Error during preLoadImage : %s " % err)
            self.onStopped()
    else:
        self.logger.warning("No ALTabletService, can't preload the image.")
        self.onStopped()

def onInput_onStop(self):
    self.onUnload()
    self.onStopped()

def _getAppName(self):
    import os
    if self.frameManager:
        behaviorPath = os.path.normpath(self.frameManager.getBehaviorPath(self.behaviorId))
        appsFolderFragment = os.path.join("PackageManager", "apps")
        if not (appsFolderFragment in behaviorPath):
            self.logger.error("appsFolderFragment is not in behaviorPath")
        fragment = behaviorPath.split(appsFolderFragment, 1)[1]
        #Additional code:from here
        fragment = fragment.split('/')[1]
        #Additional code:So far
        return fragment.lstrip("\\/")
    else:
        self.logger.warning("No ALFrameManager")
```